# How i can write Spring-boot application for capturing and upload image by using web-cam?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, webcam-capture

i want write a spring-boot application to capture and upload image by using **WEB-CAM,** can anyone help me on this please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to implement Code to Access webcam, start by getting familiar with this project https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture

then have a look at this 15 mins tutorial on uploading files https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/